# Keeping Automatic Log of one week Transaction in PHP

Tags: php, file-put-contents

**Case:**

I have the following query for the INSERT Operation as:

```
$sql = "BEGIN -- 
pkg_transaction.set_transaction('" . $_SESSION ['user'] . "', 'INSERT EMPLOYEES'); --
                        insert into employees (EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,EMAIL, --
                        ADDRESS,USERNAME,PASSWORD) -- 
                        values ($id,'$first_name','$last_name','$email', --
                        '$address','$username','$password'); --
                        commit; --
                        pkg_transaction.unset_transaction(); --
                        END;";
```

**Attempt:**

**I have used the following function named *file_put_contents()* to create the log
of the INSERT transaction.**

```
file_put_contents('insert_transaction.log', $sql.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
```

**Current Output:**

The above method keeps the log of the INSERT transaction in a file named insert_transaction.log whenever the user inserts the data in the database.

**Required Solution:**

**Now I want to keep the transaction log every week. And after 1 week, the transaction log file to be override by the new log file for the transaction log for the next week.**

**I have searched many sites for this. But couldn't find the appropriate solution. Can anyone please suggest me the appropriate solution?**

**Suggestions are highly appreciated.**